# ruby parseexecel gem - array not implemented

Tags: ruby, excel, parsing

I am trying to work with two worksheets at the same time.

So I have code

```
require 'parseexcel'
#Open the excel file passed in from the commandline
workbook = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse(ARGV[0])
workbook2 = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse(ARGV[1])

#Get the first worksheet
worksheet = workbook.worksheet(0)
worksheet2 = workbook2.worksheet(0)
```

However, when I run this code I get an error: `array is not implemented`

This error goes away when I comment out line:

```
workbook2 = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.parse(ARGV[1])
```

Why is this happeneing?

Way I am running script is: `ruby -rubygems traverse.rb excel.xls so.xls`

Comment: Looks like it can't parse so.xls, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by copy pasting so.xls in excel.xls as a different `workbook`. then just accessed it by `workbook.worksheet(1)` that worked